# How were Danny & Abra getting their shine to live?

Tags: plot-explanation, doctor-sleep

In Doctor Sleep (2019), some people depend on the shine, and they kill
people for that. But how were Danny & Abra getting their shine to live?

I never saw Danny & Abra killing people to consume shine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No one needed to absorb shining to live a normal length life. The group Rose the Hat led adsorbed victims' shining so they could continually stay young.

Danny and Abra didn't need to absorb anyone's shining because they never tried to live forever.